# How to put ggplot in the renderPlot in shiny r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to shiny and I have problems with putting the `ggplot` into the `renderPlot`. If the `ggplot` ran alone it works well but when I started to put it in the `renderPlot` It plotted nothing.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)

cv_continent <- read.csv("coronavirus_continent.csv")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(includeHTML("gtag.html")),
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "VISUALISATION LE COVID-19", id="nav",

             tabPanel("GLOBAL",
                       sidebarPanel(
                           width= 20,
                           span(tags$i(h1("Visualiser la revolution globale du Covid-19 pendant 4 mois\n")), style="color:#045a8d"),
                           span(tags$i(h2("Diagramme en barre")), style="color:#045a8d"),
                           selectInput("condition","Choisir observation:",
                                       choices = c("Cas","NouveauxCas","Décès","NouveauxDécès"))
                        ),

                       plotOutput("image")

                      ),

             tabPanel("Continent",
                  sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        span(tags$i(h4("Visualiser la revolution du Covid-19 par continent\n")), style="color:#045a8d"),
                        selectInput("continent","Choisir un continent:",
                                    choices = c("Asie","Europe","Amérique_du_Nord","Amérique_du_Sud","Océanie"))
                      ),
                      #mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                          tabPanel("Diagramme en barre pour chaque continent", plotlyOutput("barre")),
                          tabPanel("Diagramme sectoriel", plotlyOutput("sectoriel")),
                          tabPanel("Dendrogramme", plotlyOutput("dendrogramme"))
                        )
                    #  )

                    )     
             )
  )

)
server <- function(input, output){
 ContinentInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$continent,
           "Asie" = Asia,
           "Europe" = Europe,
           "Amérique_du_Nord" = North_America,
           "Amérique_du_Sud" = South_America,
           "Océanie" = Oceania)
  })


output$sectoriel <-renderPlot({

  sec <- cv_continent %>% 
      group_by(continent_level) %>%
      summarise(total=sum(cases)) %>%
      mutate(pourcentage= total/sum(total) * 100)  

      ggplot(sec, aes(x = "",fill= continent_level)) +
      geom_bar(aes(y=pourcentage),width=1,stat="identity")+
      coord_polar(theta = "y")+
      geom_text(size=1.5,aes(y=pourcentage,label = paste0(round(pourcentage,digits = 2), "%")), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),color="black")+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("Lightblue","#AD7366","Lightgreen","Orange","Coral","#254290"))+
      labs(x="",y="",title = "\n",fill= "Libellé de famille de métier")+
      theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
                              axis.text = element_blank(),
                              axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                              plot.title = element_text(hjust = 4, color = "#666666"))
      })



}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Here I want to plot in the section `Continent` and in the second `tabPanel` name `Diagramme sectoriel`

In case you need here is the link for csv and others files: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/tree/master#

Any help for this would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `plotOutput("image")` I don't see "image" defined anywhere.

Comment: Also, `output$sectoriel <-renderPlot({` doesn't return anything. you need a `return(sec)`

Comment: ```plotOutput("image")``` It works for me so I did not put it. I want to focus on the ```plotOutput("sectoriel")```

Comment: Ahh okay where should I put the ```return(sec)``` at the end of the code?

Comment: I put ```return(sec)``` but it does not work

Comment: You are using plotlyOutput, not plotOutput in your UI. plotlyOutput is looking for a plotly chart not ggplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)

cv_continent <- read.csv("coronavirus_continent.csv")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(includeHTML("gtag.html")),
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "VISUALISATION LE COVID-19", id="nav",

             tabPanel("GLOBAL",
                       sidebarPanel(
                           width= 20,
                           span(tags$i(h1("Visualiser la revolution globale du Covid-19 pendant 4 mois\n")), style="color:#045a8d"),
                           span(tags$i(h2("Diagramme en barre")), style="color:#045a8d"),
                           selectInput("condition","Choisir observation:",
                                       choices = c("Cas","NouveauxCas","Décès","NouveauxDécès"))
                        ),

                       plotOutput("image")

                      ),

             tabPanel("Continent",
                  sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        span(tags$i(h4("Visualiser la revolution du Covid-19 par continent\n")), style="color:#045a8d"),
                        selectInput("continent","Choisir un continent:",
                                    choices = c("Asie","Europe","Amérique_du_Nord","Amérique_du_Sud","Océanie"))
                      ),
                      #mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                          tabPanel("Diagramme en barre pour chaque continent", plotOutput("barre")),
                          tabPanel("Diagramme sectoriel", plotOutput("sectoriel")),
                          tabPanel("Dendrogramme", plotOutput("dendrogramme"))
                        )
                    #  )

                    )     
             )
  )

)
server <- function(input, output){
 ContinentInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$continent,
           "Asie" = Asia,
           "Europe" = Europe,
           "Amérique_du_Nord" = North_America,
           "Amérique_du_Sud" = South_America,
           "Océanie" = Oceania)
  })


output$sectoriel <-renderPlot({

  cv_continent %>% 
      group_by(continent_level) %>%
      summarise(total=sum(cases)) %>%
      mutate(pourcentage= total/sum(total) * 100) %>% 
      ggplot( aes(x = "",fill= continent_level)) +
      geom_bar(aes(y=pourcentage),width=1,stat="identity")+
      coord_polar(theta = "y")+
      geom_text(size=1.5,aes(y=pourcentage,label = paste0(round(pourcentage,digits = 2), "%")), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),color="black")+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("Lightblue","#AD7366","Lightgreen","Orange","Coral","#254290"))+
      labs(x="",y="",title = "\n",fill= "Libellé de famille de métier")+
      theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
                              axis.text = element_blank(),
                              axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                              plot.title = element_text(hjust = 4, color = "#666666"))
  })



}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thank for your idea I edited it a little bit now and it works. i deleted the ```sec``` in ```ggplot``` and put ```%>%``` after ```mutate```

Comment: Overlooked that, sorry! I editted the answer to reflect that